# Handling of null and [] (empty list)

Tags: elasticsearch, null, nosql, elasticsearch-query

I am very new to Elasticsearch and I have a question regarding the handling of `null` and `[]` (empty list) values. Specifically, in my `dummy` index example, I have a document as follows

```
{
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "dummy",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4c9bc4adbd5f572d708428f3df4dbf55",
                "_score": 17.805637,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 81863,
                    "created_at": "2022-06-14 10:23:31",
                    "updated_at": "2022-06-14 10:23:31",
                    "meta_data": "",
                    "acl": {
                        "species": null,
                        "roles": null,   <--- null value
                        "tools": null
                    },
                    "category": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here, it is noticeable that the field `acl.roles` is `null`. Additionally, in the same index, there is another document which looks like this

```
{
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "dummy",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "10a0a66bf7b60ed28e1ced36bd59934a",
                "_score": 15.609104,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 65690,
                    "created_at": "2020-10-02 09:46:00",
                    "updated_at": "2020-10-02 09:46:00",
                    "meta_data": "a:0:{}",
                    "acl": {
                        "species": [],
                        "roles": [],    <--- empty list
                        "tools": []
                    },
                    "category": "PERSONAL"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So in the `dummy` index, the field `acl.roles` can have either a `null` value or an `[]` (empty list) value. Could you guys please explain to me:

- What is the difference between `null` and `[]` in Elasticsearch?
- Is it possible to count the number of documents that have `acl.roles=null` and `acl.roles=[]`? If so, what is the difference between the two queries? I try to do a query like below but I don't really understand how Elasticsearch handle these stuff ??

```
GET dummy/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "acl.roles"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand something, please, point it out for me, I really appreciate that.

Thank you guys !!!

Answer (score 0):

A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as though that field has no values.

1.There no differences between null and [] in Elasticsearch.

2.You can not count documents that have acl.roles=null and acl.roles=[] respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you save `null` or empty list into a field, there is no value to be stored into reversed index. That is why it does not matter if it is an empty list or `null`, and that's why you can not filter nor count on such values.

From docs: When a field is set to null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as though that field has no values. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html)